# Can kubernetes shared single GPU between pods?

Tags: kubernetes, gpu

Is there a possibility to  share a single GPU  between  **kubernetes** pods ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-gpus/scheduling-gpus/#v1-8-onwards) says

> GPUs are only supposed to be specified in the limits section, which means:
>
> You can specify GPU limits without specifying requests because Kubernetes will use the limit as the request value by default.
>
> You can specify GPU in both limits and requests but these two values must be equal.
>
> You cannot specify GPU requests without specifying limits.
>   **Containers (and pods) do not share GPUs**. There’s no overcommitting of GPUs.
>
> Each container can request one or more GPUs. It is not possible to request a fraction of a GPU.

Also, you can follow [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52757) discussion to get a little bit more information.

Comment: apparently this isn't quite true - see my answer :)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible - at least with Nvidia GPUs.

Just don't specify it in the resource limits/requests. This way containers from all pods will have full access to the GPU as if they were normal processes.

Comment: In this case how will the pod know to attach to a GPU node?

Comment: It won't attach to GPU, but will have access to all GPUs - there's no need to attach anything. If you need to control access, then you have to take care of it yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I was probably not wording it appropriately. My perception is that I need to tell the pods somehow to start on a node that has a gpu so it can use the GPU, right? How would I do that if I do not use resource requests?

Comment: @niid I do it with node labels and node selectors

Comment: thanks. does it work on any version of Kubernetes?

Comment: yes, GPU access is unrelated to Kubernetes, and node labels/selectors is a very old feature in k8s

Comment: Does this still work? If I don't request a GPU, at least in GKE, I am getting "WARNING: The NVIDIA Driver was not detected.  GPU functionality will not be available."

Comment: sorry, I have no experience with GKE or any other shitty "clouds" :)

Comment: > If you need to control access, then you have to take care of it yourself.
@Adam Do you mind sharing what are the options for taking care of this? Or would this, in your opinion, be a good query for a new SO question?

Comment: @MarekŽidek The only access control I have is on namespace level, so that each namespace has access to selected nodes, which I've achieved using the `PodNodeSelector` admission controller.

Comment: Am I right if I say that this approach would be bad in multi-user environment? GPU is an expensive resource and for some non-priority applications it is mandatory to set limits and restrict access to the whole GPU.

Comment: @VladimirVisnovsky Yes, if users access the GPU directly, you need an additional layer to manage that.

Comment: @niid you do that using taints and tolerations, first taint your GPU node so that the scheduler only schedules the podswith the matching tolerations  on it. Then, in your pod's spec.templates.spec.tolerations add your key, value, operator and effect,  here's the link to the documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible by making some changes to the scheduler, someone on github kindly open-sourced their solution, take a look here: https://github.com/AliyunContainerService/gpushare-scheduler-extender

Answer (score 1):

Official docs says pods can't request fraction of CPU. If you are running machine learning application in multiple pods then you have to look into kubeflow. Those guys have solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [nano gpu](https://github.com/nano-gpu) for sharing gpu of nvidia.

Comment: nano-gpu is gone from github. but there is https://github.com/elastic-ai/elastic-gpu-scheduler now.

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be to partition an Nvidia GPU into fully isolated instances with their own high-bandwidth memory, cache, and compute cores - https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/technologies/multi-instance-gpu/.